# Change AutoIndex number Mysql

Tags: mysql

In my table I have auto increment id which is having its number like 1 to 66,440 and next number is 88846790 + increment from here till 88846900.

There is no records in between 66440 to 88846790

I want my next auto increment number to be 66441 but its taking 88846791, can you help me in setting next auto increment to 66441,

Comment: For all future visitors to this question: never attempt to set an auto increment value lower than the greatest ID in the table. You will run into trouble as your rows count up to and conflict with existing rows. Your table will likely develop gaps in the auto increment sequence - this is expected and fine, the point of auto increment is that the field won't have any semantic meaning, so gaps cause no problems. If you are in danger of running out of the `2,147,483,647` usable integer space, consider making the field unsigned or `BIGINT`, or rebuild your data (and manage your references).

Comment: For all future visitors to this question:  Also, note that the ALTER (in 6 answers) does not work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
alter table tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=664441
```

should do

Comment: @Tim Dinh has a valid point, remove all rows having auto_incr value >664440

Comment: @ Satya I can Not remove those numbers, i need it those number as well

Comment: @Siddhesh, then I do not think , you have a way out other than copy records to another table , and removing the  rows having auto_incr value >664440 from this table . And when querying you need to have a join of both the tables

Comment: The autoincrement value should always be greater than the max value in the table. Even if you manage to change it to a lower value (which I doubt you can) it will probably break in ugly ways...

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke you should take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html as well for auto_increment and here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: Downvoted because it does not work.  (See my Answer for reference to manual.)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `ALTER TABLE` to change the auto_increment value:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 66441;
```

See the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for more details.

**Remember to reinsert all rows with an id higher than 88846790**

If you don't remove rows with a higher ID than 66441,

the change in autoincrement does nothing.

**Example:**

```
 ID    Value
----  --------
  1      C
  2      A
  4      D
 50      A
 51      C
```

If I want to change auto increment to `5` I need to remove or re-insert the `50` and `51` first. Because otherwise the next auto increment is gonna be `52` anyway.

Depending on how much and how important the data is, often the best thing to do is: **Nothing**

Because those primary ID's have relations to other rows, and maybe even web- urls based opn those IDs.  This will all fail, unless you create some sort of script.

Comment: Remember to reinsert or remove all the rows with an id higher than 88846790. Please read the answer, and try...

Comment: No, you either do nothing about it, or you create a small script to re-insert all rows and adjust auto increment.

Comment: Tnx for the example, it means there is no way to to set auto increment to 5 without removing 50 & 51 ...??

Comment: No, this will break the idea of primary Id's. So it will not work otherwise.

Comment: Or `UPDATE t SET ID=ID - 50 + 4 + 1 WHERE ID >= 50`

Answer (score 4):

I had trouble getting this to work in phpMyAdmin, even inputting the query directly. If you browse the table you want to reset the index of, then click `Operations`, you should be able to set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` directly under `Table options`. Then just click Go and you're all set!

Answer (score -1):

*Rebutal to all those recommending ALTER:*

> **You cannot reset the counter** to a value less than or equal to the
> value that is currently in use. For both InnoDB and MyISAM, if the
> value is less than or equal to the maximum value currently in the
> AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reset to the current maximum
> AUTO_INCREMENT column value plus one.

-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

(That is from the 8.0 manual, but I believe that it has always applied; I think I discovered it in 4.0 days.)

*Better than deleting and re-inserting:*

Renumber the higher values:

```
UPDATE t SET id = id - 88846790 + 66440 + 1 WHERE id >= 88846790;
```

But then comes the hassle of renumbering references to this id.  They can use a similar update:

```
UPDATE other_table SET t_id = t_id - 88846790 + 66440 + 1 WHERE t_id >= 88846790;
```