# Which one is faster to get the row? The primary key that carries numbers or that carries characters?

Tags: mysql, sql

| ID (Int 11) (Primary key) (Auto increment) | TITLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |
| 4 | ... |
| 5 | ... |
| To 10 million rows |  |

| ID (Char 32) (Primary key) | TITLE |
| --- | --- |
| a4a0FCBbE614497581da84454f806FbA | ... |
| 40D553d006EF43f4b8ef3BcE6B08a542 | ... |
| 781DB409A5Db478f90B2486caBaAdfF2 | ... |
| fD07F0a9780B4928bBBdbb1723298F92 | ... |
| 828Ef8A6eF244926A15a43400084da5D | ... |
| To 10 million rows |  |

*If I want to get a specific row from the first table, How much time will take approximately, Same thing with the second table, How much time will take approximately?*

*Is the primary key that carries numbers will be found faster than that carries characters?*

*I do not want to use auto-increment with int like the first table because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482554/change-autoindex-number-mysql)*

Comment: *I do not want to use auto-increment with int like the first table because of this problem* 99% that something (or somebody) tries to insert the row with this big AI column value.

Comment: No matter what PK you use, someone/something could mess with it.  And it is theoretically possible that two different things can have the same MD5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to tell the exact times needed to retrieve a specific record, because it depends on lots of factors.

In general, numeric values take less storage space, thus scanning the index requires less I/O operations, therefore are usually faster.

However in this specific case the second table looks like a hexadecimal representation of a large number. You can probably store it as a binary value to save storage space.

On top of the above, in general numeric values are not affected by various database and column settings, while strings are (like collation), which also can add some processing time while querying.

The real question is what is the purpose of using the binary representation. 10 million values can easily fit in INT what is the need to have a key which can store way more (32 long hexadecimal value)?

As long as you are within the range of the numeric values and there is no other requirement, just to be able to store that many different values, I would go with an integer.

The 'problem' you mention in the question is usually not a problem. There is no need to not have gaps in the identifiers in most caes. In fact in lots of systems, gaps are naturally occurring during normal operations. You most probably won't reassign the records to other IDs when one record is being deleted from the middle of the table.

Unless there is a semantic meaning of the ID (it should not), I would just go with an AUTO_INCREMENT, there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If the admin entered 2147483647 manually into the id column, The next new row will not be inserted because it is reached the maximum

Comment: If an admin drops the table, you lose all data. Same principle. You should not insert values manually into an AI column (also you should not drop table if you don't want to lose the data). Educate your admins, or if they are using a GUI, simply don't give them the option to set the values of the AI column. If a DBA messes this up, they should be able to fix it (they should not mess it up in the first place).

Comment: You're right, If an admin intentionally inserts a new row away from the admin panel, the problems that will happen are his own doing. Also to be careful I'll educate the admin on what should not do. Thank you.

Comment: Gaps can occur in AUTO_INCREMENT for so many reasons (rollback, delete, crash, replace, ignore, etc) that I recommend against such if you really need a gapless id.

Comment: @RickJames You are totally right and I agree with you. However as a note to the topic: the need for gapless IDs is usually just cosmetics  (user don't want to see gaps, because of any arbitrary reason), if there is a real need for a gapless ID, that means the records in the table are related in some way and might be better to organize said data in a different way (like having a link to the parent record and the chain of parents are describing the order or having a timestamp indicating time order)

Comment: @Pred - Meanwhile, I bled all over the link to "this problem" that the OP mentioned.  I included straightforward code to close up a gap; there were 6 answers that were _incorrect_.

Answer (score 2):

UUIDs and MD5s and other hashes suck because of the "randomness" and lack of "locality of reference", *not* because of being characters instead of numeric.

You *could* convert those to `BINARY(16)`, thereby making them half as big.

```
10M INT         =  40MB  = 600/block
10M CHAR(32)    = 320MB  = 300/block  
10M VARCHAR(32) = 330MB  = 300/block
10M BINARY(16)  = 160MB  = 450/block
```

Add that much more for each secondary key in that table.

Add again for each other table that references that PK (eg, FOREIGN KEY).

Let's look at the B+Tree that is the structure of the PK and secondary indexes.  In a 16KB block, some number of entries can be placed.  I have estimated them above.  (Yes, the 'overhead' is much than an INT.)  For `INT`, the BTree for 10M rows will probably be 3 levels deep.  Ditto for the others.  (As the table grows, Varchar would move to 4 levels before the others.)

So, I conclude, there is little or no difference in how many BTree blocks are needed to do your "point query".

Summary of how much slower a string is than an INT:

- BTree depth -- little or none
- Cachability of index blocks -- some; not huge
- CPU time to compare numbers vs strings -- some; not huge
- Use of a fancy `COLLATION` -- some; not huge

Overall -- not enough difference to worry about.

What I will argue for in some cases is whether you need a fabricated PK.  In 2/3 of the tables I build, I find that there is a 'natural' PK -- some column(s) that is, by the business logic, naturally `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`.  These are the two main qualifications (in MySQL) for a `PRIMARY KEY`.  In *some* situations the speedup afforded by a "natural PK" can be more than a factor of 2.

A [*Many-to-many mapping table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) is an excellent (and common) example of such.